# 'rename' on files with apostrophes

Tags: bash, rename

I'm trying to batch rename some files using the `rename` utility (specifically the perl version, i.e. `prename`).  Unfortunately, the file names contain apostrophes, and it's messing things up.  I'm not sure how to proceed.

Here's what I've tried:

```
rename -n '/.*(\d\d).jpg/Foo's Excellent Photo - $1.jpg/'  # fails due to end of string
rename -n '/.*(\d\d).jpg/Foo\'s Excellent Photo - $1.jpg/' # fails due to end of string
rename -n "/.*(\d\d).jpg/Foo's Excellent Photo - $1.jpg/"  # fails due to shell expansion
```

What is the correct syntax?

Comment: What version of rename are you using? None of my research suggests using regexp type transformations. Also, your regexp suggests the name with the apostrophe is what you're converting ~to.~ Is that mandatory? Can you go without the apostrophe?

Comment: It's the Perl rename utility, which is packaged for Debian/Ubuntu.  See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14327613/rename-multiple-files-from-command-line for an example.  Keeping the apostrophe is the point of the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Your last variant is the correct one to use single inside double quotes -- but you have to escape also the `$1` otherwise the shell will expand it:

   ```
   "/.*(\d\d).jpg/Foo's Excellent Photo - \$1.jpg/"
   ```
2. However, I still get the error

   ```
   Bareword found where operator expected at (eval 1) line 1, near "/.*(\d\d).jpg/Foo's"
       (Missing operator before Foo's?)
   syntax error at (eval 1) line 1, near "/.*(\d\d).jpg/Foo's Excellent "
   ```

   But this is not because of wrong quoting, but because `perl-rename` expects a perl regex. And you obviously want to search and replace, so use `s/.../.../`, not only `/.../.../`.
3. So, summing up, this command works flawlessly:

   ```
   $ rename -n  "s/.*(\d\d).jpg/Foo's Excellent Photo - \$1.jpg/" *
   PIC44.jpg renamed as Foo's Excellent Photo - 44.jpg
   PIC45.jpg renamed as Foo's Excellent Photo - 45.jpg
   ```

Comment: Thanks! I was using s///, but forgot to put it in my question.